# ¿Cómo insertar imágenes en el HTML con java script (correctamente)?

Tags: javascript

Tengo 4 imagenes en mi HTML, todas con mas de 1000px de ancho. Quiero que estas imagenes se cambien por otras más pequeñas cuando alguien ingrese con un movil. Esto no lo puedo hacer con media queries, porque yo necesito la etiqueta html **IMG** y NO una imagen como fondo de un contenedor. No sé si esta forma de agregar imagenes (con js) sea la correcta, porque he leido que Google prefiere que se agregue el contenido HTML directamente (y no con js), pero es la unica manera que me queda, puesto que mi diseño se basa en contenedores que se estiran segun el contenido (no tienen tamaño fijo), y para poner una imagen de fondo necesitaria establecerle un tamaño a mis contenedores, cosa que me haria renovar mucho codigo, y a estas alturas no puedo.

estoy pensando en hacer algo asi:

```
//css
@media (max-width : 480px) {

  img {
    display : none
  }

}

//js
if ( window.innerWidth < 481 ) {
  //jq
  $( '<img src="img/.jpg" />' ).appendTo( 'body' );
}
```

Lo que necesito saber es si esta es la forma de hacerlo. Si es correcto, o si no es recomendado. Gracias.

Comment: No es mejor hacer la imagen con porcentajes? En otro caso, si se puede con media queries, podrías agregar alguna imagen de tu proyecto para entender un poco mejor?

Comment: te refieres a hacer pequeña una imagen de 1000 pixeles con porcentajes??????? eso se puede hacer pero no se debe, creo.....o sea seria una imagen muy pesada para una resolucion pequeña

Answer (score 2):

Si tu prioridad no son los navegadores viejos, tienes la posibilidad de usar el atributo srcset

```
<img src="img-mobile.jpg" 
     srcset="img-mobileHD.jpg 2x, 
             img-tablet.jpg 768w, 
             img-tabletHD.jpg 768w 2x, 
             img-large.jpg 1200w, 
             img-largeHD.jpg 1200w 2x" />
```

Puedes leer mas informacion acá.

https://carlosazaustre.es/imagenes-responsive/

Comment: Definitivamente seria buena idea utilizar `srcset`, pero OP aun no deja muy claro el proposito de las imagenes, si son pensadas para fondos no se si sea la mejor idea

Comment: aparentemente quiere especificarla en el src, pero no las quiere como fondo del contenedor, ahora no deja claro si el proposito final es para cover, slideshow o carrusel.

Comment: Interesante! No sabia que existia esa forma (ahora queda ver si es compatible al menos con internet explorer 9)........ Las imagenes son parte de un slider. Y necesito que ocupen su espacio "fisico" de alto, y que su ancho se calcule automaticamente...si las pongo como fondo, debere establecerle al contenedor un tamaño de alto y ancho, cosa que no puedo hacer ahora...no quiero complicarme a estas alturas  que ya tengo todo el diseño terminado, sino tendria que modificar mucho, establecerle tamaños a muchos contenedores, hacer calculos extras, etc...cambiar todo

Comment: El hecho concreto amigos es que necesito cambiar el tamaño de las imagenes segun la resolucion de pantalla. No es para que sea dinamico, y alguien presione un boton y se cambien, es para que tengan el peso correcto, segun el aparato con el que se visualicen. Y, repito, no quiero imagenes de fondo, por una cuestion de diseño que ya tengo establecido, necesito imagenes en el HTML, con la etiqueta IMG... Quiero saber si lo que estoy haciendo es la forma correcta, o si hay otras maneras...o si no me lo recomiendan..

Comment: No, no puedo usarlo. Es demasiado incompatible. No acepta opera mini ni blackberry, ni ningun internet explorer, y de IOS a partir del 8......no me puedo arriesgar

Comment: pues dadas tus condiciones, no diría que tu código es incorrecto o no, mas bien diría que es la única forma de hacerlo, ya que cada opción expuesta te conlleva a un inconveniente..

Comment: Tengo curiosidad de que clase de sitio estas construyendo que Blackberry Browser te parece un porcentaje de usuarios importante (0.02%) jaja

Comment: No es solo blackberry, fijate que dice que no soporta ningun internet explorer.....ademas, es desagradable cuando le dices a alguien "ingresa a mi pagina", la persona entra, y te dice "no se ve bien" ...y cuando la revisas esta desconfigurada por incompatibilidad...es feo saber que hay opciones de que eso pase...por eso prefiero tener cubiertos al menos los aparatos basicos, como son iphone 3 o 4 para arriba, internet explorer 9 para arriba, opera mini

Comment: Bueno no se si leíste el articulo, pero el en el src especificas la imagen en tamaño móvil, es decir si el navegador no es compatible con srcset te va a cargar esa imagen de todos modos,  por lo cual no debes preocuparte por blackberry y otros móviles, para IE9 es el problema, Aunque siendo honesto yo me burlaria mas del usuario que usa IE9 mas que el hecho que me diga que la pagina no se ve bien.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con @AquilesPerez, en este punto seguir enllavado con IE9 es no solo desfasado, sino hasta un serio problema de seguridad que no vale la pena tratar (en mi opinion) creo que lo *basico*, es precisamente lo mas comunmente utilizado actualmente

Comment: Ponlo de esta manera, sacrificarás las preferencias de google por el contenido de la pagina, por unos 0.01% de usuarios de internet, garantizandole a ese 0.01% a traves de javascript su imagen.

Comment: bueno eso que dices que la imagen original se cargará en caso el navegador no soporte el srcset, esta muy bien...pero eso otro que dices que internet explorer 9 es el unico que seguiria siendo un problema, me preocupa......¿por qué razon internet explorer no actúa como los otros navegadores, que cuando no soportan el srcset simplemente muestran la imagen original ?..o es que no te entendi bien?

Comment: Ummm no, me entendiste mal, internet explorer también mostrará la imagen especificada en el src, a lo que me refiero con "problema" es que al definir la imagen de tamaño móvil en el src no se verá bien ya que IE9 es una cosa que solo puedes usar desde desktop por lo cual se cargará la imagen pero si no tiene muy buena calidad se verá distorsionada

Comment: O en caso contrario puedes poner por defecto la imagen con mejor calidad en promedio, de modo que se vea "decente" en desktop y bien en movil, solo que claro, el golpe puede venir en movil si la imagen es mas pesada; es por esto que tienes que pensar en que vale mas la pena segun tu necesidad; pero definitivamente yo no recomendaria hacer tanto trabajo extra por garantizar la experiencia mas optima para usuarios de IE9; el solo seguir usando ese navegador les da una experiencia de menor calidad

Comment: Exacto, totalmente de acerdo @IvanS95

Comment: @IvanS95 Me puedes decir por favor ¿donde hay un buen manual de java script desde cero hasta avanzado?..tu pareces tener un buen nivel por eso te pregunto donde aprendiste. Te queria mandar privado pero veo que aqui no hay esa opcion.

Comment: @natan en realidad yo lo he ido aprendiendo al usarlo; conociendo otros lenguajes de programacion lo hace mas facil jaja; pero te recomiendo que le des un vistazo a las guias que ofrece W3Schools o freeCodeCamp, son excelentes, aunque estan en ingles, si tienes problemas con el ingles puedo talvez encontrar otras guias, pero muchos tutoriales incluso en Youtube pueden serte de ayuda

Comment: @natan [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/) .... [FreeCodeCamp](https://guide.freecodecamp.org/javascript/) ... Tambien puedes buscar cursos en español en Udemy si puedes invertir dinero en ello, algunos son muy buenos y a mi me han servido mucho... Sin embargo ten en mente que JavaScript, es un lenguaje de programacion, no de maquetado o estilos... por ende mucho en el se tiene que pensar con logica y algoritmo... puede haber muchas formas de hacer el mismo trabajo, asi que tienes que practicar el analisis del problema

Comment: youtube es bueno para cuando recien empiezas pero al final te das cuenta que no es tan bueno como un manual....el de w3school es bueno pero tambien esta un poco limitado me parece. Pensaba que conocias otro mas poderoso, y si esta en español seria genial..Lo malo es que no hay un manual oficial de java script como si lo hay con php-

Comment: @natan te recomendaria cursos en Udemy, puedes encontrarlos en español y son excelentes... Aqui tambien te dejo una guia oficial de Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: y cuestan?-----